# Why does a black box appear in the render instead of a window when using the Archimesh add-on?

Tags: rendering, add-on, archimesh-add-on

My window looks fine in the viewport. But when I go into into rendered mode, its just a black box.

Viewport:

[image: Viewport]

Rendered mode:

[image: Rendered mode]

Comment: Please show an image of the material used for the windows.

Comment: click the wall and in the tool shelf -> create -> archimesh -> room tools -> click auto holes

Comment: I have the same problem in Blender 3.4.1 - I see a black box in the viewport instead of the Archimesh when using Cycles in render preview mode. I see the Archimesh item in the viewport as expected in render preview mode when switching to Eevee.
The Archimesh item is rendered as expected in a proper render when using Cycles, so this issue is in the viewport in render preview mode only.